# Why fmt.Println(float64(1/2)) shows 0?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(float64(1/2))
}
```

Why it prints: 0

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/KGgao6n8lTA

Is it because `fmt.Println` precision is low?

Comment: `1 / 2` is `0`.

Comment: You need to convince it to use floating point division sooner. As it is, `1` integrally divided by `2` is `0`; and then, `0` as a float is `0.0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order of operations here is: `1/2 = 0` (integer division truncates decimal places) followed by `float64(0) = 0`, then `fmt.Println(0)`.

So in short: the integer division is truncated to 0. Everything else works fine.

As @Amadan commented, you can force a floating point division by casting one of the integers, i.e. `float64(1) / 2 = 0.5`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought Go's constant is special as it makes the resulting constant "infinitely" precise (e.g., 1/3.0 is 0.3333....., not limited to float64). But forgot that by definition 1/2 is 0.