# Operator precedence in Go in formula V = 4/3πr3

Tags: go, operators

Trying to set the formula of the volume of a sphere V = 4/3πr3

I coded `V = 4 / 3 * math.Pi * math.Pow(r, 3)` but not `V = (4 * math.Pi * math.Pow(rˆ3)) / 3`.

I get that there is operator precedence to be considered, but in this situation, I don't see where it may interfere on the desired result, afterall, there are no other operators besides `*`, `/` and `math.Pow`.

Comment: `math.Pow` isn't an operator, it's a function call, but precedence for `/` and `*` are equal so they will be evaluated left to right.

Comment: Operator precedence is detailed in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators

Comment: From the left, `4 / 3` is integer division and evaluates to `1`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566992/why-fmt-printlnfloat641-2-shows-0/54567021#54567021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is as follows:

```golang
V = 4.0 / 3.0 * math.Pi * math.Pow(r, 3)
```

As JimB stated by default `4 / 3` will be an integer division as and such will round significantly. You can force a float division by specifying the data type with `4.0 / 3.0`.

Comment: Thanks John and Jim!

That is exactly what was happening, the rounding.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to find the volume of sphere :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func volume(radius float64) float64 {
    return 4.0 / 3.0 * math.Pi * math.Pow(radius, 3)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(volume(5.0))
}
```

Output:

```
523.598775598299
```